# Postgresql select from two tables where the second table has multiple values in a single column

Tags: regex, postgresql

Im trying to run a select between two columns, where the second column has multiple values i.e.

DB Used is a postgresql database.

```
Table1
number | date     | 
27     | 27-07-20 |
30     | 30-07-20 |
7969   | 30-07-20 |

table2
numbers      | date     |  Name  |
27 2927 3134 | 27-07-20 | test   |
30 2721 79   | 30-07-20 | test1  |
```

Now my query works on exact matches i.e. the 7969, but when it comes to smaller digits, the query picks up on multiple items that start with the number, i.e. 27 is like (27, 2927,2721) ect.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT f.name,e.number, f.numbers
FROM table1 e JOIN
 table2 f
 ON f.numbers like '%' || e.number || '%'
```

Anyone have any ideas how I can join the two table by looking up the number in table 2?

Comment: First, what is the dataType of  `table1 number` and `table2 number` columns.

Comment: @Abdel-Raouf, just text columns at this stage

Comment: you mean that you deal with strings ?

Comment: Yes they would be strings

Comment: as stated by the Docs: `If pattern does not contain percent signs or underscores, then the pattern only represents the string itself; in that case LIKE acts like the equals operator.`. So please try using `f.numbers like e.number` , and tell me the result :)

Comment: throws an error ERROR:  operator does not exist: text ~~ bigint

No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: if i specifically cast as : f.numbers::varchar like e.number::varchar

The query executes but only returns 6 rows instead of the entire table

Comment: It returns the 6 rows that matches what you want, that means that  `27` not equal to `2729273134` so it doesn't return it as before ?!

Comment: Im expecting that it show null for the ones it cant match and show all rows from table1

Comment: Do **not** store numbers as strings, never.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your numbers are all separated by non-digit characters, create an `integer` array from your `numbers` column using `regexp_split_to_array()` and casting, and then test with `= ANY()`.

```
SELECT f.name,e.number, f.numbers
  FROM table1 e 
       JOIN table2 f
         ON e.number = ANY(regexp_split_to_array(f.numbers, '[^\d]')::int[])
```

If your numbers are always separated by a single space character, then use `string_to_array(f.numbers, ' ')` as it is less costly.